# Several Starcounter applications on one server with many domains

Tags: starcounter

I have seen no built in support in Starcounter to do site bindings, for example in the same way Internet Information Server where you can route calls to a specific site depending on domain name used as per the picture below. Is there any recommended way to how to work do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Starcounter you can setup multiple domains in the ReverseProxies configuration section of the scnetworkgateway.xml file.

Example:

```
<ReverseProxy>
  <DestinationIP>127.0.0.1</DestinationIP>
  <DestinationPort>8080</DestinationPort>
  <StarcounterProxyPort>80</StarcounterProxyPort>
  <MatchingHost>my.website.com</MatchingHost>
</ReverseProxy>
```

Read more on [starcounter.io](http://starcounter.io/) - [Reverse proxy functionality](http://starcounter.io/guides/network/networkgateway/#reverse-proxy-functionality).